# Solving $y''=\lambda y$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

"Show that all solutions of $y''(x)=\lambda y(x)$ on $0\leqslant x \leqslant L$ with $y(0)=y(L)=0$ are of the form $c\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}\right)x.$ (Hint: write down all solutions of the o.d.e and impose boundary conditions.)"

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvBp8.png) is an image from the textbook I'm using describing this problem. I'm not sure what the hint means; what entails "writing down all solutions"? I'm not sure what method I should use to begin approaching this problem.

Comment: This is the classic problem in elementary physics, leading to a standing wave on a string.

Comment: That's a basic 2nd order ODE, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: This is a homogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients. Do you know how to solve such equations with characteristic polynomials/equations?

Comment: All solutions of $y''(x)=\lambda y(x)$ with $\lambda<0$ would be $c_1\sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x)+c_2\cos(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x)$

Comment: I could obtain something like $A\textrm{cos}(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\textrm{sin}(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$ but I am not sure how to justify that I am "writing down all solutions". Edit: oops just saw the comment above, sorry for redundancy.

Comment: @user771918 I have seen others using characteristic polynomials to solve this equation, but it's not something explicitly covered in my course content, so I don't think I'm supposed to. For reference, I am using Strichartz's the Way of Analysis.

Comment: @minivase That's odd. I would imagine textbook gives you some tool to solve such an elementary ODE.

Comment: Is it possible that I could argue that all solutions are in this form by arguing using uniqueness and existence from turning it into a linear first order system?

Comment: @minivase Yes, that's a possibility. You'd have to show that every possible initial condition can be satisfied by linear combinations of the appropriate $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions. It seems like overkill though.

Comment: @minivase: I have added an answer that sketches how to prove completeness via a first order system. The proof is rather long, and probably you are not supposed to show completeness in your excercise at all. And there are other ways to show completeness, for example through Fourier analysis, but that even requires more prior knowledge, so I have opted for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the auxiliar equation $m^2= \lambda$. If $\lambda<0$, $\lambda= -\alpha^2$. You have $m^2=-\alpha ^2$. The solutions are $m_1= \alpha i$ and $m_2=-\alpha i$. The solution is $y(x)=c_1 \cos (\alpha x) +c_2 \sin (\alpha x)$. Now $$ y(0)= c_1=0$$ $$y(L)=c_2\sin (\alpha L)= 0$$ Then $\sin (\alpha L)=0$. So $\alpha L=\pi k$ then $ \alpha = \pi k / L$. The solution is $$y(x)=c_2 \sin \left (\dfrac{\pi k}{L} x \right )$$

Comment: How does this justify that all solutions are necessarily of this form?

Comment: If you have that $\lambda \geq 0$, so $\lambda= \alpha^2$. Then you have the equation $m^2= \alpha^2$ the solutions are $m_1=\alpha$ and $m_2=- \alpha$. The solution is $y(x)= c_1 e^{\alpha x}+ c_2^{-\alpha x}$. $$y(0)=c_1 + c_2=0$$  $$y(L)=c_1 e^{\alpha L}+ c_2^{-\alpha L}  =0$$. The solutions are $c_1=c_2=0$ You have the trivial solution $y(x)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The unique solution of $y''=\lambda y$ with $y(0)=0,\;y'(0)=1$ is
$$
              y_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
This works in the limiting case as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, which is $y_0(x)=x$. So the only $\lambda$ for which there is a non-trivial solution of $y''=\lambda y$ with $y(0)=0,\;y(1)=0$ are the values of $\lambda$ for which $y_{\lambda}(1)=0$. $\lambda=0$ does not work, but $\lambda=n^2\pi^2$ does work for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. So the only solutions of $y''=\lambda y$ with $y(0)=y(L)=0$ are those for which $\sqrt{\lambda}=n\pi/L$ or $\lambda=n^2\pi^2/L^2$. So the solutions of the eigenvalue problem are multiples of
$$
                  \sin(n\pi x/L),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots .
$$

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already provided the solutions, I will only elaborate on the completeness proof of the solution set, which seems to be of particular interest to you.

I am not sure if you are already supposed to know the math (linear algebra, complex analysis) for your excercise, but let's see. Also, there are probably other ways to prove it.

As you have already proposed in the comments, you can prove completeness in this special case by transforming the second order ODE into a first order ODE system and finding the solutions by straightforward integration, which ensures that you do not miss a solution.

You can transform $y^{\prime\prime}=-\alpha^2 y$ to first order by the substitution
$$z := \frac{y^\prime}{\alpha}$$
This equation and the substituted one can now be written in the matrix form
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \begin{array}{c} y\\z\end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \alpha\\-\alpha & 0\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{c} y\\z\end{array}\right)$$
or more simply
$$q^\prime=Aq$$
You can diagonalize the matrix $A$ (if you multiplied it by the imaginary unit, it would become hermitian and hence, diagonalizable) by finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors
$$Aq_\kappa=\kappa q_\kappa\qquad or \qquad AQ=QK$$
The eigenvalues can be found by setting
$${\rm det}(A-\kappa I)=\kappa^2+\alpha^2=0$$
which results in
$$\kappa_{1,2}=\pm i\alpha$$
So the corresponding eigenvectors solve the equations
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} -i\alpha & \alpha\\-\alpha & -i\alpha\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{c} y_1\\z_1\end{array}\right)=0\qquad {\rm and} \qquad \left( \begin{array}{cc} i\alpha & \alpha\\-\alpha & i\alpha\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{c} y_2\\z_2\end{array}\right)=0$$
which leads to $z_1=iy_1$ and $z_2=-iy_2$ and hence (after normalizing the eigenvectors so that $Q$ becomes unitary),
$$Q=\left( \begin{array}{cc} i\sqrt{1/2} & -i\sqrt{1/2}\\ \sqrt{1/2} & \sqrt{1/2}\end{array}\right) \qquad , \qquad K=\left( \begin{array}{cc} i\alpha & 0\\0 & -i\alpha\end{array}\right)$$
Now you can transform the first order ODE to the eigenbasis of $A$ which results in a diagonal ODE system
$$q^\prime=Aq=QKQ^+q \qquad i.e. \qquad p^\prime := Q^+q^\prime = KQ^+q=:Kp$$
In components of $p=(p_1,p_2)^T$, this equation reads
$$p_1^\prime = i\alpha p_1 \qquad {\rm and} \qquad p_2^\prime = -i\alpha p_2$$
Each of those can be integrated elementarily, which makes it impossible to miss a solution (**and so eventually, proves completeness**). For example the first one:
$$i\alpha =\frac{p_1^\prime}{p_1}=\frac{d}{dx}({\rm ln} (p_1))$$
$${\rm ln} (p_1)=i\alpha x + c_1$$
$$p_1=a_1\cdot {\rm e}^{i\alpha x}=a_1 \cos(\alpha x)+i a_1\sin(\alpha x)$$
Similarly for $p_2$:
$$p_2=a_2\cdot {\rm e}^{-i\alpha x}=a_2 \cos(\alpha x)+i a_2\sin(-\alpha x)$$
Then you only have to transform the general solution for $p$ back to $q$, i.e.
$$q=Qp$$
and impose the reality condition for $q$ (to find allowed coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$), which results in the general sine/cosine solutions others have already pointed out. After imposing the boundary conditions you have the wellknown solutions, which you have now shown to be complete.